# Symfyony is throwing DateTime Parse Error

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime, symfony-1.2

I'm trying to get `created_at` field from database table but it's throwing the below error:

> Internally stored date/time/timestamp value could not be converted to
>   DateTime: '
>
> Cook
>
> ' [wrapped: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to
>   parse time string (
>
> Cook
>
> ) at position 0 (<): Unexpected
>   character]

**Code for fetching date:**

```
foreach ($pager->getResults() as $row):
         ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row->getTitle()  ?></td>
          <td><?php echo ($row->getStatus()) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' ?></td>
          <td><?php echo date(sfConfig::get('app_display_alternate_format_for_date'), strtotime($row->getCreatedAt())) ?></td>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Config for Date:

> 'app_display_alternate_format_for_date' => 'M-d-Y'

**Date save in DB format:**

> 2017-09-15 08:08:02

**Base getCreatedAt function at BaseModel:**

```
public function getCreatedAt($format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
    {
        if ($this->created_at === null) {
            return null;
        }


        if ($this->created_at === '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            // while technically this is not a default value of NULL,
            // this seems to be closest in meaning.
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                $dt = new DateTime($this->created_at);
            } catch (Exception $x) {
                throw new PropelException("Internally stored date/time/timestamp value could not be converted to DateTime: " . var_export($this->created_at, true), $x);
            }
        }

        if ($format === null) {
            // Because propel.useDateTimeClass is TRUE, we return a DateTime object.
            return $dt;
        } elseif (strpos($format, '%') !== false) {
            return strftime($format, $dt->format('U'));
        } else {
            return $dt->format($format);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the exception looks like it finds the string `Cook` in the field.
I'd `var_dump($this->created_at);exit;` a line before the `new DateTime($this->created_at)` to exclude this possibility.

Once you're confident this is not the case, try giving the format of the string. Instead of `new DateTime()` use:

```
$dt = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->created_at);
```

or, better:

```
$dt = date_create_from_format($format, $this->created_at);
```